# How to limit user to input max 2 or 3 digits after decimal separator in EditText(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext, limit, enter, digits

I have the following class:

```
public class DecimalFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    //Pattern mPattern;
    String regex = "[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (2 - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
    {
        //mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
        regex = "[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString(), regex))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have two EditText on which I set the filter like that:

```
discountEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalFilter(2) });
quantityEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalFilter(3) });
```

When I run the application and try to input something in these EditTexts I am not able to enter even a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class DecimalFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    String regex = "[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (2 - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
    {
        //mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?"); 
        regex = "^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1)  + "})?$";

    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {

        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString(), regex)||dest.ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }

        return new Java.Lang.String( string.Empty);
    }
}
```